# Selecting nth level child to manipulate width of the DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on Zoom-in and Zoom-out section of my site. The issue I'm facing is i'm not being able to get the `<div>` with `class=product-view` .

Below is the HTML code I have:

```
<div id="tabs-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="drag-drop-box ui-droppable">
    <div class="component ui-draggable dropped" style="position: relative;">
       <div class="product-view">
           <a href="#"><span>C</span> us-east-1c</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And this is the Jquery code I'm using:

```
$("#zin").click(function(){
  var wid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').width();
  var getid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').attr('id')
  alert(wid);
  alert(getid);
  $('#'+getid > div > div).children('.product-view').css('width','90px');
});
```

Can anyone suggest what needs to be done to serve the purpose? Thanks

Comment: This : `$('#'+getid '> div > div')` would already actually mean something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML>

```
<div id="tabs-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="drag-drop-box ui-droppable">
    <div class="component ui-draggable dropped" style="position: relative;">
       <div class="product-view">
           <a href="#"><span>C</span> us-east-1c</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<input type="button" id="zin" value="zoom in"/>
<input type="button" id="zout" value="zoom out"/>
```

CSS >

```
.product-view{
    border:1px solid black;
    font:bold 12pt 'Tahoma';
    display:table;
}
.product-view.expanded{
    font:bold 24pt 'Tahoma';
}
```

JQuery >

```
    $("#zin").click(function(){
      var wid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').width();
      var getid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').attr('id')

    $('#'+getid + '> div > div').children('.product-view').addClass('expanded');

    });
$("#zout").click(function(){
      var wid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').width();
      var getid = $('div[aria-hidden="false"]').attr('id')

    $('#'+getid + '> div > div').children('.product-view').removeClass('expanded');

    });
```

Comment: I think this is actually you want

Comment: There's no point to the wid and getid variables. It's just extra junk.

Answer (score 3):

Try to concatenate your selector using `+` here:

```
$('#' + getid + '> div > div').children('.product-view').css('width','90px');
```

or you can shorten your selector using **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**:

```
$('#'+ getid).find('.product-view')
```

Comment: Thank you all for such quick reply and worthy suggestions. All of them worked as desired but unfortunately I can mark only one correct answer. Upvoted all the posters. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The way you had concatenated the string into the selector is wrong please try,

```
$('#'+getid + '> div > div').children('.product-view').css('width','90px');
```

and i would suggest you to use `.find()` in your context.

Try,

```
$('#'+ getid).find('.product-view')
```

or use a descendant selector like,

```
$('#'+ getid + " .product-view")
```

Comment: Thank you all for such quick reply and worthy suggestions. All of them worked as desired but unfortunately I can mark only one correct answer. Upvoted all the posters. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just:

```
$('div[aria-hidden="false"] .product-view').css('width','90px');
```

Comment: Thank you all for such quick reply and worthy suggestions. All of them worked as desired but unfortunately I can mark only one correct answer. Upvoted all the posters. Thanks a lot, i really appreciate your help.